# Turning nested class into descriptor without instantiating it

Tags: python, descriptor

Note: Python version is 2.7

### Problem

**I want** to have {hierarchy of descriptor classes} integrated within {hierarchy of widget classes}, and overriding descriptor behaviour must be as easy as defining nested derived class. Example:

```
class A(object):
    class width(Attribute):
        def changed(self, obj, value, old):
            print 'A.width changed:', value

class B(A):
    class width(A.width):
        def changed(self, obj, value, old):
            super(B.width, self).changed(obj, value, old)
            print 'B.width changed:', value

B().width = 10
# must print:
#     A.width.changed: 10
#     B.width.changed: 10
```

Here is my custom descriptor class:

```
class Attribute(object):

    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_name'):
            self._name = self.__class__.__name__

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            print 'Attribute getter (class):', cls
            return self

        print 'Attribute getter (class, inst):', (cls, obj)
        print 'Attribute getter returning:', self.get(obj)
        return self.get(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print 'Attribute setter (inst, value):', (obj, value)
        self.set(obj, value)

    def get(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__dict__[self._name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("attribute '%s' referenced before assigment" % (self._name))

    def set(self, obj, value):
        try:
            old = obj.__dict__[self._name]
        except KeyError:
            obj.__dict__[self._name] = value
            self.changed(obj, value, None)
        else:
            obj.__dict__[self._name] = value
            if old != value:
                self.changed(obj, value, old)

    def changed(self, obj, value, old):
        pass
```

**Problem is** that Python don't want to use `__get__` and `__set__`, while they are attributes of class. It may be seen from this test:

```
# `A` and `B` were defined above
A.width_ = A.width()
B.width_ = B.width()

to_test = (
    # good:
    'Aw_ = A.width_',
    'Bw_ = B.width_',
    'B().width_ = 10',
    # silent:
    'Aw = A.width',
    'Bw = B.width',
    'B().width = 10',
)

for expr in to_test:
    print "Testing:", expr
    exec expr
```

So, my `Attribute` works only when instantiated.

### What I have tried already

- Decorating `__get__` and `__set__` with either `staticmethod` or `classmethod`. No changes in silent section. Good section fails: methods aren't callable. Wat.
- Adding `__get__` and `__set__` to class `Attribute` from outside, as methods bound to `Attribute`. Nothing changed.

Code:

```
# `__get__` was renamed to `_unbound__get__`
Attribute.__get__ = Attribute._unbound__get__.__get__(Attribute, Attribute.__class__)
# `__set__` was renamed to `_unbound__set__`
Attribute.__set__ = Attribute._unbound__set__.__get__(Attribute, Attribute.__class__)
```

- Using instantiated descriptors. This approach requires 2 symbols: one for descriptor (sub)class and one for descriptor. It also requires instantiating descriptor after subclassing it.

Code:

```
class B(A):
    class Width(A.width):
        def changed(self, obj, value, old):
            super(B.width, self).changed(obj, value, old)
            print 'B.width.changed:', value
B.width = B.Width()
```

### More background.

I have growing hierarchy of widgets, where some propertries must be tracked for changes, and response to change may be extended in subclassses. So I am trying to create automated approach, with modular machinery. Because keeping relevant variables and methods per each propertry inside actual widgets is just horrible annoying mess.

### Question

Are there workarounds to achieve my needs? Or may be I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at how existing frameworks have addressed the design of this (and considered adopting their approaches?) eg: QT / WxWindows, in terms of events/attributes and inheritance models? Or, is this a "I want to do it this way - how can I make this way happen if it's possible?"

Comment: Descripors need to be instantiated. Where's the problem in using an instance? Read [how descriptors work](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#invoking-descriptors)

Comment: @mata Because using instances involves 2 names: one for descriptor subclass and one for descriptor instance.

Comment: I believe what you cannot achieve what you want. Basically you want `width` to be, at the same time, both a class and an instance. You cannot allow both `class width(A.width)` *and* doing `A().width = 10`. Choose one. The best you can achieve is automatically convert names(e.g. you create the `Width` class and then use `A().width = 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Descriptors *require* instances, so you *cannot* achieve exactly what you want. In particular you want `A.width` to be, *at the same time*, both a class and an instance of that class, which is impossible. You **must** have a way to access the class and the instance separately.

It's pretty simple to automatically create the instances with a known naming scheme. For example using a class decorator:

```
def track_attributes(cls):
    for attr in dir(cls):
        value = getattr(cls, attr)
        if isinstance(value, type) and issubclass(value, Attribute):
            # probably require more checks and/or different naming scheme
            setattr(cls, attr.lower(), value())
    return cls
```

Used as:

```
@track_attributes
class A(object):
    class Width(Attribute):
        def changed(self, obj, value, old):
            print 'A.width changed:', value

@track_attributes
class B(A):
    class Width(A.Width):
        def changed(self, obj, value, old):
            super(B.Width, self).changed(obj, value, old)
            print 'B.width changed:', value
B().width = 10
```

output:

```
$python test_attributes.py 
Attribute getter (class): <class '__main__.B'>
Attribute setter (inst, value): (<__main__.B object at 0x7fc225cd7d50>, 10)
A.width changed: 10
B.width changed: 10
```

An other way to achieve this without explicit decorators is to create a metaclass and have a `Widget` base class for all widgets.

Answer (score 0):

As mata says, descriptors needs to be instances. One possible solution would be to use a class decorator or a custom metaclass (in your case more probably a custom metaclass) that would lookup the class namespace for `Attribute` subclasses and instanciate them. The whole thing smells a bit like overengineering to me but sometimes well you just need that level of complexity.